# How to check whether a python web application is compatible with gevent?

Tags: python, gevent, cpython

Currently we have several web applications(written with Django) which work well under `gunicorn`'s default sync worker, and we want to use its `gevent` worker to get a better performance.

It is known that several operations which have side-effects may cause problems when `gevent.monkey.patch_all()` is used:

1. Read and write global variables including static class variables and so on. Read and write global variables between `greenlets` may get unexpected results.
2. 3rd-party libs that using C extension (mysqlclient etc). Generally there should be no problems though IO/timeouts may be blocking in the C extension. But if the C extension stores some global state variables, `gevent` may cause some unexpected behaviors. And I wonder that if there are any problem when non-blocking IO or multithreading is used in the C extension.

Now the problem comes for:

1. How to check if any global variables may be read/write by two or more `greenlets`? Or generally, is there any global variable writing operations in our web applications?
2. How to check if a C extension module is compatible with `gevent`?

For the first problem we have an idea:

Add hooks code in cpython. For every `PyObject` we create two lists to store IDs (or something like) of `greenlets` which read or write the object. Rebuild cpython and run our application with real workload to check. But it seems too complex to implement.